# Wi-Fi Problems with Lenovo Notebook and Windows11 with AX200 Adapter

Tags: wireless-networking, lenovo-laptop, wifi-configuration, wifi-driver

I have a notebook (Lenovo Legion 5 pro) with Windows11 installed. My wifi hangs all the time and disconnects regularly. I have already updated the Wi-Fi Driver for my AX200 Adapter.

Does anyone of you have the same issues with the AX200 or Lenovo Notebook?
Does anyone have a solution for this problem? Or hint?

[image]

Comment: Did You use the lenovo system update utility to check all the drivers/bios of the laptop?
https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds012808-lenovo-system-update-for-windows-10-7-32-bit-64-bit-desktop-notebook-workstation
Also check from control panel, network sharing center, change adapter settings, that your wi-fi card is not in a disabled state (it could happen with docking stations).
And also that you accidentally do not press the fn key that disable wi-fi (especially if you find it disabled in the control panel step).

Comment: Update the firmware in your Router and also try a different location (different wireless AP).

Comment: Is this still the solution, when other notebooks with wifi work fine with the same hotspot?

Comment: I have AX200 Wireless on my own ThinkPad and it works fine (Cisco Wireless), so yes I suggest updating Router firmware to see if that is the issue